# Mucking cards with an all in side pot

Tags: texas-hold-em

I was playing in a cash game.  here's how it played out.  4 players...  flop came.  I am first to act and go all in.  The other 3 players call.  They bet the turn and the river comes.  Player next to me checks.. next player checks.  Last player who is actually the dealer,  bets big.  Other two players fold and the last player (dealer) then throws his cards without showing.  He thinks he wins my pot too.  He then pulled his cards back saying they didn't touch the mucked cards.  So he took both pots.  If he threw his cards without showing, is that considered a mucked hand??  Or can he take them back out of the middle of the table and play them against my hand?

Answer (score 2):

good question, A floor person can rule the hand live, in the best interest of the game. If I was called for such s decision I would rule the hand dead. I believe players should own thier actions and I don't often go out of my way to protect prople from themselves.